# Why does JRuby's read_nonblock block?

Tags: ruby, jruby, nonblocking

I'm trying to add error logging to a JRuby process that reads data from stdout of one subprocess, and writes this data to stdin of another subprocess, while collecting some statistics on the data. The subprocesses are spawned using `IO.popen4`.

To read the error streams, I can't use blocking reads because in the normal situation there is no output on those streams. However, when I use `read_nonblock` on those streams, I still experience blocking reads in JRuby.

Why do the `read_nonblock` calls block and how could I rewrite this code so it never blocks and always displays any stderr that either subprocess outputs?

Below is a simplified version of the code I'm using that reproduces the problem. It blocks on jruby and doesn't display the expected output on `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]`.

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM != "java" && RUBY_VERSION =~ /^1\.9/
  class IO
    def self.popen4(*args, &block)
      require "open4"
      Open4::popen4(*args, &block)
    end
  end
end

IO.popen4('echo', 'hi') do |_, _, stdout1, stderr1|
  IO.popen4('sh', '-c', 'cat 1>&2') do |_, stdin2, _, stderr2|
    stdout1.each_line do |line|
      stdin2 << line
      (IO.select([stderr1, stderr2], [], [], 0.1) or [[]]).first.each do |stream|
        begin
          # in jruby 1.6.8 (ruby-1.9.2-p312) (2012-09-18 1772b40) (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.6.0_37) [darwin-i386-java], read_nonblock blocks
          # idem in jruby 1.7.2 (1.9.3p327) 2013-01-04 302c706 on Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909 [darwin-i386]
          puts stream.read_nonblock(1000)
        rescue Exception => e
          puts e.message
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I know it is blocked in read_nonblock because of the stack trace when pressing ctrl+\:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=0000000003110800 nid=0xb0201000 runnable [00000000b01ff000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.read(FileDispatcher.java:26)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:198)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:171)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.read(FileChannelImpl.java:144)
- locked <0000000006158308> (a java.lang.Object)
at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream.refillBuffer(ChannelStream.java:196)
at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream.bufferedRead(ChannelStream.java:926)
at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream.bufferedRead(ChannelStream.java:888)
at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream.fread(ChannelStream.java:1288)
- locked <000000000615a8f8> (a org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream)
at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream.readnonblock(ChannelStream.java:1314)
- locked <000000000615a8f8> (a org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream)
at org.jruby.RubyIO.getPartial(RubyIO.java:2762)
at org.jruby.RubyIO.read_nonblock(RubyIO.java:2697)
at org.jruby.RubyIO$INVOKER$i$0$1$read_nonblock.call(RubyIO$INVOKER$i$0$1$read_nonblock.gen)
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodN.call(JavaMethod.java:646)
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:204)
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
at read_nonblock_test.chained_2_rescue_1$RUBY$SYNTHETIC__file__(read_nonblock_test.rb:19)
at read_nonblock_test.block_3$RUBY$__file__(read_nonblock_test.rb:16)
at read_nonblock_test$block_3$RUBY$__file__.call(read_nonblock_test$block_3$RUBY$__file__)
at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock19.yield(CompiledBlock19.java:139)
at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:130)
...
```

Comment: Mine blocks (1.6.8) but *always* returns EAGAIN.  I have yet to find *any* way to detect-data-but-not-block with a pipe in jruby:

Answer (score 2):

So, this is a pretty offensive solution, but it's what worked for me.  Since select always returns "yes", and nonblock just doesn't work, I don't see another choice:

```
      require 'timeout'
      begin
        while true
          line = nil
          Timeout::timeout(1) { line=io.gets }
          if line.nil?
            break
          else
            puts "line: #{line}"
          end
        end
      rescue Timeout::Error
      end
```

-Robin

Answer (score 0):

(this isn't really an answer, more a continuation of the problem)

Mine never blocks (1.6.8) but *always* returns EAGAIN.  I have yet to find *any* way to detect-data-but-not-block with a pipe in jruby:

```
jruby-1.6.8 :001 > io=IO.popen('sh -c "sleep 10"') ; select([io],nil,nil,0)
 => [[#<IO:0x6e72d873>], [], []]
jruby-1.6.8 :003 > sleep 10 ; begin ; io.read_nonblock(1) ; rescue Exception => e ; puts "nothing: #{e.class.name}" ; puts "#{io.eof?}" ; end
nothing: Errno::EAGAIN
true
 => nil
jruby-1.6.8 :001 > io=IO.popen('sh -c "sleep 10"') ; select([io],nil,nil,0)
 => [[#<IO:0x6e72d873>], [], []]
jruby-1.6.8 :006 > require 'fcntl'; io=IO.popen('sh -c "sleep 10"') ; puts "f: #{io.fcntl(Fcntl::F_GETFL)}" ; io.fcntl(Fcntl::F_SETFL, Fcntl::O_NONBLOCK) ; puts "f: #{io.fcntl(Fcntl::F_GETFL)}" ; puts "e: #{io.gets}"
f: 0
f: 0
e:
 => nil
jruby-1.6.8 :007 > io=IO.popen('sh -c "echo foo ; sleep 10"') ; select([io],nil,nil,0) ; begin ; io.read_nonblock(1) ; rescue Exception => e ; puts "nothing: #{e.class.name}" ;     puts "#{io.eof?}" ; end
nothing: Errno::EAGAIN
false
 => nil
```

Not that read_nonblock returns EAGAIN when data is present!  And at EOF!  0.o

-Robin

Comment: wait *shouldn't* it raise EAGAIN? I mean if you call it a second or third time does it raise it too?

Comment: I raises EAGAIN *every time*.  Even if there's data waiting, which is exactly the opposite of what EAGAIN means.  Even if the FD is at EOF, which is against the docs.

Comment: It's a bug (everything mentioned here is a JRUBY bug), MRI gets it right, and there is already a bug opened ( http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6235 ) which got closed even though it isn't fixed for many people, so it got re-opened ( http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-7110 ) and ignored. -__-

Comment: On a related note that isn't at all relevant here, I can't see how to get a jira account for jurby, at all, and hence I can't comment on that bug, or even submit one; if anyone knows how, that'd be helpful to me.

Comment: good question I don't see a way...maybe ping the jruby forum?